# How to check whether nothing in ViewData[]

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have  code to store data to  `ViewData["bill"] = lstbill;`where `lstbill`  is of type  `List<Checkout> lstbill;` .Sometimes listbill having count as 0.Then how can I check `ViewData["bill"]` contains value or not in razor view?

Comment: Don't use `ViewData` - use a model/view model

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
   var lstbill= ViewData["bill"] as List<Checkout>;
   if(lstbill==null||lstbill.Count<1){
   <span>No Bill</span>
   }
```

Comment: I think you mean `.Count` (not `.Length`)

Comment: You are welcome, I was hesitating between but I finally corrected!